# Code to fetch intermediate certificate automatically

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

When you install an SSL certificate you should include the intermediate certificates as well.

I handle a lot of SSL certificates and I spend a lot of time tracking down intermediates along the chain.

I want to write code that will fetch intermediates automatically. 
I use python and java and I don't care much about the implementation. ( either running commands and parsing the output or using some native API ).

It seems to me such a useful algorithm that I believe someone already wrote it.

1. Is there an openssl command that can do this? searched for it but couldn't find.
2. Is there a better way to go at it - using python / Java..

thanks.

Comment: Do you use a large number of CAs to get your certificates?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to write code that will fetch intermediates automatically

It is possible to do that provided that the end certificate i.e. the one you are trying to validate contains information on where to find the issuer CA certificate (via `http` or `LDAP` for example) in the `AIA` extension of the `X.509v3` certificate.
Then you can download that certificate and continue in the same process (i.e. look into the `AIA` to get the issuer's issuer certificate) until you build the whole chain for validation.

This of course implies that you already have a `PKI` in place (not just create certificates yourself e.g. via `OpenSSL`)

Comment: Do you know if there's an openssl command for this already, or which interface would you recommend python, java, or none - simply run openssl commands and parse the results - or maybe there's an openssl command to return the CAI from the AIA?